# Esconder div para versão mobile com css

Tags: css

Eu estava pesquisando aqui as soluções, mas não funcionou no meu código, deixo aqui ele:

**CSS:**

```
    @media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
   #img{ 
            display: none !important; 
        } 
}


    #img{
       background-color: none;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-6" id="img">
            <img src="img/book.png" width="650px" height="800px"  style="margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -50px">
        </div>
```

Mas não está funcionando. O que estou fazendo de errado? Aperto <kbd>F12</kbd> para simular um celular, mas não rola.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, qual DIV você está tentando esconder?

Comment: O id que vc informou no style, não esta associado a nenhum elemento da página

Comment: a resposta do amigo, não funcionou

Comment: Cara coloca seu CSS completo ai! Edita a pergunta e coloca ele inteiro! Seu problema deve ser em outra parte do código, pois aqui funcionou

Comment: editado a pergunta

Comment: estou usando o bootstrap, não sei se interfere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara! Vi que vc está usando Bootstrap, usa uma coisa massa do bootstrap 4. vc faz o seguinte:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 d-sm-none" id="img">
```

O d-sm-none quer dizer que quando o tamanho da tela for considerado sm (small) essa div n será exibida, precisa nem "cutucar" no css lkkkkkkk

Comment: eu consegui exatamente com este comando! top

Comment: Hehehe tmj cara

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        #img{ 
            display: none !important; 
        } 
    }
    #img{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

<div class="col-sm-6" id="img">
  <img src="img/book.png" width="600px" height="800px"  style="margin-top: -100px">
</div>
```

Sua referência de ID não está correta. Tente dessa maneira, e lembre-se de referenciar os ID's de forma correta.

Comment: não funcionou cara